# Can't reach router controller on loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, loopbackjs

I have a little application in Loopbak where I created a Customer model based on the built in User model. Automatically Loopback serves the api with all the methods (GET,POST,PUT...) and it seems to handle by itself (I'm newbie and yet don't understand the "magic" behind it). However, I need a custom route to handle the request. I did this:

```
module.exports = function(server) {
    var router = server.loopback.Router();

    router.post('/customers', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req);
    })

    server.use(router);
}
```

but when I use the post method against the customers path, it doesn't reach the console.log. I don't know if I need to do something in the middleware.json or something and the documentation is a little vague for me (at least in this moment).

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Loopback mounts REST API at `/api` by default. `/customers` and `/api/customers` are different.